# Geometric probability problem

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

I have been practicing some problems and I got stuck on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Text of the problem is in the picture that I have attached, also there is a part of solution that I think I did right. I have done several similar problems and got confused at the last part. What value of theta should I use? Or should I use something with absolute theta, if yes, why?(absolute(theta)>pi/3 my assumption). Should I say that 0 lessthan theta lessthan pi?

Also, as you can see on the picture in the bottom, in this case, I am not sure what value would theta denote (of which angle). And how would you finish this problem to get the probability?

Edit: Equilateral triangle should be in text. I just forgot to write "triangle".
[image]

Comment: "If we randomly pick a point inside a circle..." $~$ How? $~$ That is: What is the probability distribution of the point's distance from the centre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help if you draw a graph of $\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)$
and see for yourself what values of $\theta$ satisfy the inequality
$\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right) > \frac{\sqrt3}{2}.$
It should be clear that 
$\theta > \frac{4\pi}{3}$ gives you a lot of values of $\theta$
that do *not* satisfy that inequality.

Instead, the inequality is satisfied when
$$\frac{2\pi}{3} + k\pi < \theta < \frac{4\pi}{3} + k\pi$$
for $k$ an integer.

Looking at what $\theta$ means, we see that $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$
gives us something that looks like your first figure, such that
the length of the segment $XY$ is $\sqrt3 R.$
If we increase the angle to $\theta = \pi,$ then $XY$ is a diameter
of the circle, and its length is $2R.$
If we continue increasing the angle, we start measuring the angle of the
*longer* arc between $X$ and $Y,$ and the length of $XY$ decreases as
$\theta$ increases.

But of course $\theta$ is not a property that describes the position of
the midpoint $E,$ at least not in any really direct way.
It is about as good a description of the position of $E$ as the length
of the chord $XY$ is.

To get a probability, you need to find something you can say about $E$ itself. Since you can rotate the diagram around the center of the circle
without changing the dimensions of any part of the figure,
it's clear that the direction from the center to $E$ does not matter.
Since the direction does not matter, all you really need to be concerned
with is the distance from the center to $E.$

Let $r$ be the distance from the center to $E.$
Find all values of $r$ for which $XY > \sqrt3 R.$
Then figure out the probability that $r$ has one of those values.
Assuming that "randomly picking a point in the circle" 
means the probability distribution of the point is uniform
with respect to area, any probability measure will basically
come down to measuring the area of some region within the circle
where the necessary conditions on $r$ are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I am new here so sorry if this is mis-formatted.

First you can note that all that matters is how far E is from the center. In other words the length of $XY$ depends only on $E$'s distance from the center. So without loss of generality we can assume that $E$ lies on a convenient radius. Also WLOG we can scale so that $R=1$.

Inscribe an equilateral triangle in our circle of radius 1. Consider a radius that bisects one of its legs. By the argument in the first paragraph we can assume that $E$ lies on this radius. Then $XY$ will be longer than the leg of this triangle if and only if $E$ is above the base of the triangle. The probability of this is just the distance from the center of the triangle to the base (can be calculated as 1/2) divided by the radius (which is 1).

Hence the answer should be 1/2.